# C# Func<> and extension methods question

Tags: c#, .net, lambda

I have seen someone write below kind of Func<> pattern. And I am trying to experiment with Funcs and Lambdas to get the concepts right.

so ExperimentalSelect returns a Func (with 2 args and bool return value).

But I fail to understand that how all of the 3 return statements are valid (1 at a time).

```
public static Func<BinaryTreeNode<int>, int, bool> nodeSelector = (x, y) =>
{
    return x.Value > y;
};

public static Func<int, int, bool> intSelector = (x, y) =>
{
    return x > y;
};


public static Func<BinaryTreeNode<int>, int, bool> ExperimentalSelect (int number)
{
    return nodeSelector; // seems straightforward, i agree this should work

    // how does this work ? intSelector is different type Func<> 
    // and it is executing it here, thereby returning the bool type result 
    // and not Func<> type as the return type of this method should
    return (x, y) => intSelector(number, number); 

    // and how does this work ? what is node here ? 
    // and SomeMethod returns bool and not Func<> type
    return (node, x) => SomeMethod(node, number, true); 
}

private static bool SomeMethod(BinaryTreeNode<int> node, int someNumber,
                               bool doSomething)
{
    return node.Value < someNumber;
}
```

**EDIT:**

If an ext. method expects a func

```
IEnumerable<int> selected = tree.TakeWhile(ExperimentalSelect);
```

1. How does SomeMethod work here ?, it is not a Func<> !
2. What does this syntax mean: `(node, x) => SomeMethod(node, number, true);`

Where is the node or x in picture here ?

Comment: Please see update to my answer. Maybe this makes things a little bit clearer.

Comment: @Daniel. I saw it. makes sense. can u see my comment on your answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your comments above the returns are not correct.

`intSelector` and `SomeMethod` are **not** executed there. They will only be executed, when the return value of `ExperimentalSelect` is executed.

```
return (x, y) => intSelector(number, number);
```

This defines an anonymous method with two parameters. One of type `BinaryTreeNode<int>` and one of type int and a return value of bool, because that's what's the return type of `ExperimentalSelect`. **The body of this anonymous method is the call to `intSelector` which is executed only, when the anonymous method itself is executed**. This means, the body of this anonymous method can be anything you wish. It can even be multiple statements:

```
return (x, y) => {
                      var temp;
                      temp = y;
                      y = x;
                      x = temp;
                      return intSelector(number, y);
                 }
```

The anonymous method then is returned and not the result of executing it.
Your return statement is equivalent to the following:

```
Func<BinaryTreeNode<int>, int, bool> result = 
    (x, y) => intSelector(number, number);
return result;
```

You can verify this yourself with your debugger. Add a break point inside `intSelector` and step over the `return` statement. You will see, the breakpoint will not be hit.

One important point is the following:

`Func` can be seen as a pointer to a function.

```
Func<BinaryTreeNode<int>, int, bool> result = 
    (x, y) => SomeMethod(x, number, true);
```

This will create an anonymous method and `result` will point to that anonymous method.
However, have a look at the following code:

```
Func<BinaryTreeNode<int>, int, bool, bool> result = SomeMethod;
```

In this case, result will directly point to `SomeMethod`. No anonymous method is created here. Note the difference in the type of `result`. Because the first code only executes `SomeMethod` in the body of the anonymous method, the type of `result` doesn't need to match the signature of `SomeMethod`. But in the second code, you directly assign `SomeMethod` to `result` and thus the type of `result` must match the signature of `SomeMethod`.

More:
Look at the following code:

```
public static Func<BinaryTreeNode<int>, int, bool> ExperimentalSelect (int number)
{
    return (x, y) => intSelector(number, number); 
}

Func<BinaryTreeNode<int>, int, bool> result = ExperimentalSelect(10);
Console.WriteLine(result(30, 20)); // writes false
```

It will print `false`, although 30 is bigger than 20. Why?
The reason is, that your anonymous method has `x` and `y` as input parameters, but they are not used anywhere in its body. Instead, you pass `number` as both parameters to `intSelector`. The value of `number` is 10, and 10 isn't greater than 10.
The correct way to write this code would be like this:

```
public static Func<BinaryTreeNode<int>, int, bool> ExperimentalSelect ()
{
    return (x, y) => intSelector(x, y); 
}

Func<BinaryTreeNode<int>, int, bool> result = ExperimentalSelect();
Console.WriteLine(result(30, 20)); // writes true
```

As you can see, I now pass `x` and `y` to `intSelector`. I also removed the parameter `number` from `ExperimentalSelect`, because it is not used anywhere.

Comment: i got it. these are anonymous methods returned, right ? and the arg. type is assumed that of the return Func type. like x,y are both ints for return intSelector . and node, x are BinaryNode and int respectively for SomeMethod. These are automatically inferred.

Comment: @Munish: Not quite correct, but I explained it wrong in my answer, because I overlooked that in your question. The type of x and y are inferred from the return type of `ExperimentalSelect`. Please see update to my answer.

Comment: @Daniel. Ya thats what i meant. x and y are inferred from return type which is Func<sourcetype1, sourcetype2, resulttype> here. x and y should be of type sourcetype1 and sourcetype2

Comment: @Munish: Yes. In your case sourcetype1 is `BinaryTreeNode<int>` and sourcetype2 is `int`.

Comment: @Munish: Please see update to the answer. I added more important info.

Answer (score 2):

Ask yourself - are these two lines of code also correct:

```
Func<BinaryTreeNode<int>, int, bool> a = 
  (x, y) => intSelector(number, number);

Func<BinaryTreeNode<int>, int, bool> b =
  (node, x) => SomeMethod(node, number, true);
```

The answer - yes.  As it is for the return statements in your code.

I think perhaps you're either slightly misunderstanding the syntax or perhaps not understanding exactly what a `Func` is (apologies if either is not the case).

Answer (score 2):

You seem to think that in this case

```
return (x, y) => intSelector(number, number);
```

what gets returned is the `intSelector(number, number)` part. But in reality the whole thing after `return` keyword is a return value. You can rewrite it like this:

```
return (BinaryTreeNode<int> x, int y) => intSelector(number,number);
```

which is roughly equivalent to returning an anonymous delegate with two parameters of type `BinaryTreeNode<int>` and `int` which returns the value of type bool. So it's your `Func<BinaryTreeNode<int>, int, bool>` right there.

Basically, the part to the left of `=>` describes arguments and the part to the right is the method body, and the return type of the whole thing is the return type of the body.

Take a look at [Lambda Expressions article](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericwhite/archive/2006/10/03/lambda-expressions.aspx) by Eric White, it'll make sense to you.